# Making Bluetooth discoverable without user consent

Tags: java, android

I want to make bluetooth discoverable without user consent 
(The application is intended to wakeup at specific intervals be discoverable do some stuff and sleep again).
I searched and found following solutions
http://snipplr.com/view/49526/get-ibluetooth-instance/

but I am getting value of b in IBluetooth method as null and also the return value is null.

References
[How to programmatically set Discoverable time without user confirmation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742760/how-to-programmatically-set-discoverable-time-without-user-confirmation)
http://snipplr.com/view/49526/get-ibluetooth-instance/

I am using "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" but I cant use android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" as it is reserved for system apps only.