# How to make phone discoverable without user confirmation?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an app that will be run by an Android phone without touch screen (something like an embedded system then) and I need to make the system discoverable by other devices. As said I won't have the touchscreen, then everything should be done without user interaction.

I was reading this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742760/how-to-programmatically-set-discoverable-time-without-user-confirmation) but I can't make it work. As already said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809084/making-bluetooth-discoverable-without-user-consent) a NullPointerException comes out.

Is there a more detailed guide for setting up the discoverability without the user confirmation? Are there other ways to do so?

Comment: Hey Rudy :) , have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742760/how-to-programmatically-set-discoverable-time-without-user-confirmation . This solution needs aidl .

Comment: Hey Raymond, I tried that solution but I was not able to figure out how to make it work...have you tried it?