# How to create a bluetooth connection between Android device and Google Glass?

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

I am interested in using my Android phone (running my application) to do all the heavy computing/data storage for an accompanying app running on Glass. Is there a way to make a connection over wifi or bluetooth to send/receive data between the two?

Comment: @Jose Urbano Duarte Junior I saw you had a post about this. Have you made any headway in establishing a bluetooth connection? Do you know of any library that may work for this?

Answer (score 1):

For Bluetooth, you can check out [this library](https://github.com/KTlab/BluetoothCommunicationLibrary_Android).

I tested it before and I'm able to connect between my phone and Glass.

Also, [Google Glass GDK: How to Communicate with Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device) is helpful.

I haven't tried connecting over WiFi.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up building out my own Library that works great. Once it gets a little more polished I'll post it up.