# Google Glass GDK: How to communicate with an iOS device?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Right now it appears there is no Bluetooth LE support in the [GDK](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=249).

We are looking to transmit realtime athletic performance data from an iOS device to Glass.

StackOverflow refers to a [Github library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device) for Android to Glass connections using Bluetooth.

Theoretically could this be modified to work on iOS? Or is there any other protocol or approach in the GDK that would support sending data streams to Glass from iOS devices that have no Internet connection?  (i.e. such as an iPad on a golf course, soccer field etc.)

Comment: Just a point, there isn't actually a github for that project.  I'm going to get around to making it some day, but haven't yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is possible based on the documentation found here:

https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3064189

> > From an iPhone:
>
> To turn on Bluetooth on your iOS device and pair your Glass, follow
>   the steps in Apple Support. All of the functionality of Glass is
>   available via your iPhone's Bluetooth connection, with the exception
>   of SMS and turn-by-turn directions. These features require the MyGlass
>   app, which is only available for Android.

Since the pairing there would have to be done via normal Bluetooth paring mechanisms, it stands to reason that you ought to be able to utilize the normal blue tooth protocols to implement cross platform communication.

I can't swear to this as I'm not an IOS dev, but if you're able to pair, then you're through the normal Android-IOS bluetooth profile issues which limit this kind of data transfer normally.  You would obviously have to write host code on the Phone and such