# Google Glass GDK: Bluetooth discoverable Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

I try to make my Google Glass discoverable via Bluetooth in my app by calling the flowing intent:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE); 
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 120);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

But I get the following error message:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.glass/com.example.MainActivity}:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE
>   (has extras)` }

Does anyone know if this intent is supported by Google Glass right now or not?

Of course I made sure that I set the permissions in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is occurring because Glass does not have an activity registered to handle displaying the UI for that action.

Can you file a feature request in [our issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) if you need this?

In the meantime, have you explored the workaround in [this post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414642/307266) to see if it would work for you?