# Pairing Android Wearable with Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, sony-smartwatch

I'd like to ask if someone knows if it's possible to pair a android wearable device (like a smartwatch) directly with google glass to get sensor informations like heart rate. Or is this just possible with a smartwatch being coupled with both devices? I didn't found any informative resources on this question...

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Especially if your smartwatch will be Android, this can be done fairly easily.

Glass can connect to anything over Bluetooth!

[This answer contains a full set of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device) that outlines exactly what you want.