# Can Google Glass Connect to Multiple Bluetooth Devices at Once?

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, android-bluetooth, google-gdk

Situation: As soon as my Google Glass and phone connect through the standard MyGlass Bluetooth connection, I want apps that I wrote to run on both my phone and my Glass to start and create a second Bluetooth connection between each other.

Following Nathaniel D. Waggoner's question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device/31125717), my apps can successfully create a Bluetooth connection and transfer data. However, this only works when I unpair my Glass and phone so that my Bluetooth connection is the only one between the devices. If a Bluetooth connection already exists, my second Bluetooth connection will fail to be created.

**Is Google Glass only capable of sustaining a single Bluetooth connection at one time, or am I forgetting to do something in setup?**

Comment: Google Glass Enterprise Edition v1 and v2 can hold multiple Bluetooth connection at once (source: https://9to5google.com/2017/07/24/google-glass-enterprise-edition-specs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'm working under the assumption that the Explorer 2 version of google class can only sustain one bluetooth connection at a time.

Please answer if you have coaxed that version of the hardware into running two bluetooth connections at once! Or if Google comes out with a new version of glass with expanded capabilities, please answer then too.