# How to send an automated e-mail from google glass

Tags: java, android, email, google-glass, google-gdk

i am searching a solution to send an e-mail from my application for Google Glass (GDK). The E-Mail should have a picture attached, taken with Glass.

I tried the approach from [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) which should work fine on usual Android-devices, but on Glass I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError for the Mail-Class. Its not about the imported external Jar-Files, but I think its due to the fact that the class extends javax.mail.Authenticator which might not be supported on Glass.

The key functions are: I'm in my app, take a picture and that picture should be sent automatically to a predefined Mail-Address from a predefined (gmail) address.

Is there a solution for Google Glass?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is interesting... try to communicate trough bluetooth with the Glass like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device When you take the picture with the Glass, send the image trough bluetooth via BufferedInputStream. Now, the Android Device should have the image and you can send the image from the phone itself. Ones the email send ok, trigger a message to Glass with a OK thing (text, image or similar)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I decided to use a servlet i wrote a while ago where i can upload pictures and send the mail from the servlet...

Comment: Maybe you have to force the import? I think that the project is in Gradle, but just to get a clue, in maven we have a scope "provided", which means that the environment has the dependency, but if you change to "compile" (or even remove the scope tag) it'll include the jar (or you can find another RI).